# Rewrite Property within Nested Arrays

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have structure like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5af16cfdb508cf1a30ed0b38"),
    "messages" : [
        {
            "publicMessage" : {
                "message" : {
                    "includedMessages" : [
                        {
                            "image" : {
                                "url" : {
                                    "url" : "umT6Gsx6yO.jpg"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I made a mistake and stored everything in image.url.url instead of image.url.
How can I move it up to the image root?
Of course there are many documents like this and not everyone has image.url.url so update all with "where" is needed.
I tried this:

```
db.test.aggregate(
[
    { "$addFields": { 
        "messages.publicMessage.message.includedMessages.image.url": "$messages.publicMessage.message.includedMessages.image.url.url" 
    }},
    { "$out": "test" }
    ]
)
```

but it is wrong and outputs:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5af16cfdb508cf1a30ed0b38"),
"messages" : [
    {
        "publicMessage" : {
            "message" : {
                "includedMessages" : [
                    {
                        "image" : {
                            "url" : [
                                [
                                    "umT6Gsx6yO.jpg"
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) here instead, as it can process each array element and rewrite the content. It's also really a problem that presents itself in three parts, though in the simplest form it's just handled by the first listing.

#### Mapping Arrays

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "messages": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$messages",
        "as": "m",
        "in": {
          "publicMessage": {
             "message": {
               "includedMessages": {
                 "$map": {
                   "input": "$$m.publicMessage.message.includedMessages",
                   "as": "i",
                   "in": {
                     "image": {
                       "url": "$$i.image.url.url"
                     }
                   }
                 }
               }
             }
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$out": "newtest" }
])
```

This returns the document as:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5af16cfdb508cf1a30ed0b38"),
    "messages" : [
        {
            "publicMessage" : {
                "message" : {
                    "includedMessages" : [
                        {
                            "image" : {
                                "url" : "umT6Gsx6yO.jpg"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Simple projection will just act on the outermost elements of the array and output everything projected "as an array". So you use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to process each array instead.

#### Merging Nested Objects

Note that if you actually have more fields in the documents within the nested arrays then these need to be specified "explicitly" within each [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) since this is effectively rewriting each array member with the new content you specify.

If you actually have MongoDB 3.6 then you can alternately use the [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) operator as opposed to explicitly specifying every key and value. However you need to do this for "every" nesting level as you cannot just use a "dotted field path" as you can with [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/), and it may actually be far more simple to just specify each key and value "explicitly":

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "messages": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$messages",
        "as": "m",
        "in": {
          "$mergeObjects": [
            "$$m",
            {
              "publicMessage": {
                "$mergeObjects": [
                  "$$m.publicMessage",
                  {
                    "message": {
                      "$mergeObjects": [
                        "$$m.publicMessage.message",
                        {
                          "includedMessages": {
                            "$map": {
                              "input": "$$m.publicMessage.message.includedMessages",
                              "as": "i",
                              "in": {
                                "$mergeObjects": [
                                  "$$i",
                                  { "image": { "url": "$$i.image.url.url" } }
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$out": "newtest" }
])
```

#### Writing Output

You can either add [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) to the pipeline in order to write a **new collection** as you cannot write to the "same collection" you are reading from, or use [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) in order to rewrite the elements of an existing collection:

```
var batch = [];

db.test.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "messages": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$messages",
        "as": "m",
        "in": {
          "publicMessage": {
             "message": {
               "includedMessages": {
                 "$map": {
                   "input": "$$m.publicMessage.message.includedMessages",
                   "as": "i",
                   "in": {
                     "image": {
                       "url": "$$i.image.url.url"
                     }
                   }
                 }
               }
             }
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
]).forEach(doc => {
  doc.messages.forEach((m,msgIdx) => {
    m.publicMessage.message.includedMessages.forEach((i,includeIdx) => {
      batch.push({
        "updateOne": {
          "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
          "update": {
            "$set": {
              [`messages.${msgIdx}.publicMessage.message.includedMessages.${includeIdx}.image.url`]:
                i.image.url
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
    if (batch.length >= 1000) {
      db.test.bulkWrite(batch);
      batch = [];
    }
  });
});

if (batch.length >= 0) {
  db.test.bulkWrite(batch);
  batch = [];
}
```

Note that when "writing" using [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) it is not necessary to worry about things like the [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) or specifying every other possible nested key since the only thing altering the collection is the actual "update" statements. In fact since the only point of the aggregation is to "reduce" the returned data into just the form you need in order to supply the updates, it's actually then desirable to return "less" rather than a complete document.

---

#### Addendum on "Nesting" Arrays

Nesting arrays is not really a great idea, as the writes show there you really don't have much option here other than to use static array indexes in order to write new entries to the array in an atomic way without overwriting all other existing content.

Generally you want a "flatter" structure, and even in the best case you still really want unique identifiers on each array level just as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5af16cfdb508cf1a30ed0b38"),
    "messages" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b11e6b3492daf3e5df114b0"),
            "publicMessage" : {
                "message" : {
                    "includedMessages" : [
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5b11e6b3492daf3e5df114b1"),
                            "image" : {
                                "url" : {
                                    "url" : "umT6Gsx6yO.jpg"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

As long as there is a way to uniquely match each element, then you at least have a chance to perform atomic updates which don't rely on an index position and presumption that the array contents have not changed with additional entries:

```
var batch = [];

db.test.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "messages": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$messages",
        "as": "m",
        "in": {
          "_id": "$$m._id",
          "publicMessage": {
             "message": {
               "includedMessages": {
                 "$map": {
                   "input": "$$m.publicMessage.message.includedMessages",
                   "as": "i",
                   "in": {
                     "_id": "$$i._id",
                     "image": {
                       "url": "$$i.image.url.url"
                     }
                   }
                 }
               }
             }
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
]).forEach(doc => {
  var $set = { };
  var arrayFilters = [];

  doc.messages.forEach((m,mIdx) => {

    arrayFilters.push({ [`m${mIdx}._id`]: m._id });

    m.publicMessage.message.includedMessages.forEach((i,iIdx) => {
      arrayFilters.push({ [`i${mIdx+iIdx}._id`]: i._id });
      $set[`messages.$[m${mIdx}].publicMessage.message.includedMessages.$[i${mIdx+iIdx}].image.url`]
        = i.image.url;
    });
  });

  batch.push({
    "updateOne": {
      "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
      "update": { $set },
      arrayFilters
    }
  });

  if (batch.length >= 1000) {
    db.test.bulkWrite(batch);
    batch = [];
  }

})

if (batch.length > 0) {
  db.test.bulkWrite(batch);
  batch = [];
}
```

That is what would be possible if there was a way to uniquely match each array item and where you have MongoDB 3.6 with support for [positional filtered `$[<identifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) updates. It's fewer writes and does not rely on fixed index positions, as the scripting here is only using the array indexes in order to name unique identifiers for the positional updates, but the updates themselves are not reliant on that index position.

Even with such support though "nested arrays" are notoriously difficult to query. Therefore what you really should consider is instead to simply have "one level" which contains all your `"includedMesages"` and simply repeat the detail from the parent nesting on each one of those items. It might seem counterintuitve to what you may have been taught about denormalization, but the level of duplication is often outweighed by the ease of update and query.

Typical "queries" involve similar combinations of [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) in such a way which can become very complex, and is easily avoided by simply "flattening" the array structure, if not moving to a separate collection entirely.